# Error in build simple (blank) application at android qt

Tags: android, qt

I am using Qt for android the specific build is:
Qt Creator 3.3.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Built on Feb 20 2015 at 04:12:12

I upgrade the SDK platform tools to 24.3.4
I start a simple new widget application for android and build and try to run it,
I get this error:

```
15:38:54: Running steps for project Test3...
15:38:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean
del moc_mainwindow.cpp
Could Not Find D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
del ui_mainwindow.h
Could Not Find D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\ui_mainwindow.h
del main.obj mainwindow.obj moc_mainwindow.obj
Could Not Find D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\main.obj
del *~ core *.core
Could Not Find D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug*~
15:38:55: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
15:38:55: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
15:38:55: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\bin\uic.exe ..\Test3\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-builtin-memmove -std=gnu++0x -g -g -gdwarf-2 -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\Test3 -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtCore -I. -I. -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi\include -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\mkspecs\android-g++ -o main.obj ..\Test3\main.cpp
C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-builtin-memmove -std=gnu++0x -g -g -gdwarf-2 -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\Test3 -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtCore -I. -I. -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi\include -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\mkspecs\android-g++ -o mainwindow.obj ..\Test3\mainwindow.cpp
C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\bin\moc.exe -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -IC:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/mkspecs/android-g++ -ID:/QT/TestPrograms/Test3 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include ..\Test3\mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-builtin-memmove -std=gnu++0x -g -g -gdwarf-2 -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\Test3 -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\include\QtCore -I. -I. -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi\include -IC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\mkspecs\android-g++ -o moc_mainwindow.obj moc_mainwindow.cpp
C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libTest3.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libTest3.so main.obj mainwindow.obj moc_mainwindow.obj -LC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi -LC:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -LC:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/lib -lQt5Widgets -Lc:\Utils\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi -Lc:\Utils\android\ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -LC:\Utils\icu32_53_1_mingw482\lib -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib -LC:\utils\mysql\mysql\lib -Lc:\mingw491\mingw32\lib -LC:\Utils\pgsql\lib -LC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lgnustl_shared -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc
15:38:59: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
15:38:59: Removing directory D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build
15:38:59: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build" install
copy /y "libTest3.so" "D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\libs\armeabi\libTest3.so"
1 file(s) copied.
15:38:59: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
15:38:59: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" --input D:/QT/TestPrograms/build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug/android-libTest3.so-deployment-settings.json --output D:/QT/TestPrograms/build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug/android-build --deployment bundled --android-platform android-21 --jdk "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_75" --ant C:/Development/Android/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant.bat
Generating Android Package
Input file: D:/QT/TestPrograms/build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug/android-libTest3.so-deployment-settings.json
Output directory: D:/QT/TestPrograms/build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug/android-build/
Application binary: D:/QT/TestPrograms/build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug/libTest3.so
Android build platform: android-21
Install to device: No
Buildfile: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
[checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.4
[checkenv] Installed at C:\Development\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk

-setup:
[echo] Project Name: QtApp
[gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
[echo] Resolving Build Target for QtApp...
[gettarget] Project Target: Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level: 21
[echo] ----------
[echo] Creating output directories if needed...
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin\res
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin\rsObj
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin\rsLibs
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\gen
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin\classes
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin\dexedLibs
[echo] ----------
[echo] Resolving Dependencies for QtApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[echo] ----------
[echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
[subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
[echo] Handling aidl files...
[aidl] Found 2 AIDL files.
[aidl] Compiling 2 AIDL files.
[echo] ----------
[echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[echo] ----------
[echo] Handling Resources...
[aapt] Generating resource IDs...
[echo] ----------
[echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
[javac] Compiling 6 source files to D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin\classes
[javac] Note: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\src\org\qtproject\qt5\android\bindings\QtActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
[dex] input: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\bin\classes
[dex] input: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\libs\QtAndroid-bundled.jar
[dex] input: D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\libs\QtAndroidAccessibility-bundled.jar
[dex] Pre-Dexing D:\QT\TestPrograms\build-Test3-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_1-Debug\android-build\libs\QtAndroid-bundled.jar -> QtAndroid-bundled-d27c84d5cbe5d71ae5b2ebefc97bb3b6.jar
[dx] '' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [dx] operable program or batch file. [dx] '' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[dx] operable program or batch file.
[dx] '`' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[dx] operable program or batch file.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Development\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Development\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Development\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Development\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1

Total time: 3 seconds
Building the android package failed!
-- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
15:39:07: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\android_armv5\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project Test3 (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.4.1))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
15:39:07: Elapsed time: 00:13.

    enter code here
```

I work with that QT for a year and succeed to build and run many android application
and suddenly TODAY I got this error!!

Comment: It looks like you need to do a build clean, or modify your manifest or your ant settings to reflect the new SDK version you want to build against. You may also want to try cloning your sources to a new directory and try building there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but before I update the android SDK tools, I still got this message, then I search in forums and, there they told to update the SDK to the newest - but the same message remain!, I also start new QT android application and the message remain! :-(   PLEASE HELP!